# Does not show one's potential

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

One who has potential, but never gives the effort to show it.

What would be the best word or words that match this description?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most-used terms for such a person is *[underachiever](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underachiever)*, which wiktionary defines as “One who underachieves by performing less well than expected”.  But *[slacker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slacker#Noun)*, in its sense of  “A person lacking a sense of direction in life; an underachiever” may often apply too, given the “never gives the effort to show [potential]” stipulation in the question.

Comment: Slacker seems more like what I was thinking of.  Underachieving however, can involve showing potential even if performing less well than expected.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective ***unfulfilled*** might be used to describe this kind of person.

> of persons; marked by failure to realize full potentialities; *"unfulfilled and uneasy men"*
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfulfilled</sub>

It is related to not realizing rather than effortlessness, but you might not realize your potential if you do not show any effort. Thus, ***effortless*** conveys this idea too.

The opposite of what you are asking is *fulfilling your potential*. [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fulfill) has the following definition and an example with a negated sentence to convey your idea:

> **fulfill your potential**
>
> to achieve as much as your natural ability makes possible
>
> *He never really fulfilled his potential as a player.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving it a "positive" connotation, instead of negative, perhaps these can get close:

modest, humble, unpretentious, unassuming